# Regresar al layout anterior al apretar botón atrás del teléfono sin salir de la aplicación en Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout

Me gustaría que en mi aplicación cuando le diera al botón de atrás de mi móvil,se vaya al layout anterior. Por ejemplo. Es que cada vez que le doy al botón de mostrar hermanos cuando le doy a atrás me sale de la aplicación, y cuando le doy a administrador cuando le doy atrás tengo que darle muchas veces al botón para que me salga de la aplicación.

`Manifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.techobbyist.signuplogin">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Lista"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".LoginActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Clase `Lista`

```
public class Lista extends AppCompatActivity {

DbHelper db;
ListView lista;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);


    db = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);

    AdaptadorLista adapter = new AdaptadorLista(this, db.llenar_lv());
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
 } 
}
```

Actividad `content_activity_list`
[image: Actividad <code>content_activity_list</code>]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro de tu botón o del control que deseas utilizar solo debes agregar :

```
onBackPressed();
```

Con esto evitas usar `intent` y el problema de volver atrás varias veces para salir de app.

Otra solucion es agregar la funcion volver atras en el `Toolbar` se veria asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cumple la misma función que el `onBackPressed();` Para habilitar esta característica, debes seguir los siguientes pasos:

En tu clase después de inicializar tu `Toolbar` agregas :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Y en tu archico `Manifest.XML` vas a la actividad que deseas utilizar y agregas :

```
android:parentActivityName=".la_actividad_que_deseas_volver"

<meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".la_Actividad_que_deseas_volver" />
```

Ejemplo :

```
 <activity
            android:name=".calculadora"
            android:label="Calculadora"
            android:parentActivityName=".tiempo_carro1"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".tiempo_carro1" />
        </activity>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70017/discussion-on-answer-by-ashley-g-boton-atras-android-studio).

Answer (score 0):

En las actividades puedes usar un método override para capturar el evento de atrás y hacer lo que quieras. El evento se llama onBackPressed()...
Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   super.onBackPressed(); // por defecto si escribes aquí el super el botón hará lo que debía hacer si lo quitas ya no hará lo que debía de hacer y puedes programar otros comportamientos.
//Quita el super y has un finish() a la actividad o bien replanteate bien lo que quieres hacer cuando se presione hacia atrás.

}
```

Saludos y suerte!

Answer (score -1):

Es fácil, lo puedes hacer con un botón o botón de imagen:

```
BtnAtras.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent List = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ClaseALaQueQuieresRegresar.class);
            startActivity(List);
        }
    });
```